# How to transfer data from Postgres to Amazon Redshift efficiently?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have so much of data in my local **Postgres database** on my machine.
I need to denormalize the data present in this local database and get a query set in specific format which can be loaded directly into Redshift tables directly using **Python**.

I do have queries that I can run on the local database and get the query set in specific format that needs to be loaded to **Redshift** directly.

But there is so much data that I need to move from local to **Redshift**. For now, the only better way I could think of is exporting the queryset that I got into a **.csv** file which will be uploaded to an **S3 bucket** which will be directly copied into the Redshift tables using Python.

I'm just wondering if there is any alternative way to do this. something like streaming directly from **Postgres database** to **AWS Redshift**

Please let me know if the uploading and dumping the **.csv** is a better way or is there any other efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: This sounds like an ETL job which is probably not the best use case for python. If you really really want to do it in python, using `sqlalchemy` would be the best case scenario that I can think of to stream the data into redshift. Bandwidth constraints as always will apply.

Comment: Actually I am supposed to use raw SQL queries because of performance issues. And I need to be denormalizing and loading the data from local DB into Redshift when even a flask endpoint is hit.

Comment: Sounds like a possible use-case for AWS Glue. AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) might also be suitable. Alternatively, if you are saving the data to S3 and loading into Redshift, make sure your Python program uses the `COPY` command on Redshift to load the data efficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other option you have and might be a better option is to use AWS DMS (Database Migration Service).

See: [Using a PostgreSQL Database as a Source for AWS DMS - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html)